# Is it possible to draw to a device context after DWM thumbnail is drawn?

Tags: winapi, windows-7

I registered a thumbnail on a window of another window. (dwmRegisterThumbnail())
I want to draw on top of the thumbnail but I can't as drawing of thumbnail is handled by DWM.

Is this possible?

Comment: Like to know that too. Any DWM thumbnail is topmost and any control on the same handle is always below the DWM thumbnail.

Comment: I found out that this program can draw on top of thumbnails, but I can't figure out how: http://ontopreplica.codeplex.com/